# --watch command is obsolete?

Tags: sass, scss-lint

```
--watch command
```

no longer works for scss. What's the equivalent

Bought a new pc and can't get newest version of sass to compile

This is going to be marked as duplicate but please point me in right direction

Comment: Just answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56846398/sass-is-not-watching) so you can check it out

Comment: I think it is not his exact answer.

Comment: @TonyNgo That was it thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think so.
As the [official SASS website](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/cli/ruby-sass#watching-and-updating) explained, you can use --watch command like this:

```
sass --watch <input file or folder>:<output file or folder>
```

To install sass on your new machine you can use this command:

```
npm install -g sass
```