# SASS is not watching?

Tags: css, ubuntu, sass

I have installed SASS on Ubuntu as explained in the [instructions](https://sass-lang.com/install), which means that I downloaded the source [dart-sass-1.22.2-linux-x64.tar.gz](https://github.com/sass/dart-sass/releases/tag/1.22.2), extracted it and added a path variable into my `.bashrc`.

Calling

```
sass input.scss output.css
```

will create the css file from scss source as explained in the [guide](https://sass-lang.com/guide).

However, when entering

```
sass --watch input.scss output.css
```

nothing happens. The file `output.css` is not updated when `input.scss` is saved. There is also no message like

> Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.

as I have seen in various other posts. This is how my terminal looks:

[image]

Any ideas why sass is not watching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same issue like you and this config work. I create 2 folder scss and css like 
this

[image]

Then I create 1 scss file inside scss folder then I run

```
sass --watch scss:css
```

Then result

[image]

Comment: Wow this actually worked! Thank you. I created an issue on the git repository https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/2719, looks like a bug to me

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot the `:` my example is this: `sass --watch assets/css/main.scss:assets/css/main.css`